# Custom login form for Azure webapp with SAML authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, saml

we are currently developing a new web app with Azure B2C as IDP. The authentication method is SAML2.0, and everything is working well. But when a user wants to login, the web app is redirecting the user to the Microsoft login form, is it possible to use our custom login form?

I know are some possibility to rebrand the login form like logo and background, but it still have the Microsoft look and feel. I tried to create a user flow in Azure B2C, but i don't have the option to choose the authentication method SAML.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This is standard across all Microsoft security products e.g. ADFS.

You always have to use the Microsoft login screen.